# Pass Pointer to function or array to function

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to figure out what I am doing wrong. I have the problem down to a few lines of code. The program will freeze or behave incorrectly when code is used.
 Just wondering if I am passing this correctly for the array's?

```
void callFunction(uint8_t &channel)
{
        uint8_t address[8]; //1wire wire address and CRC
    uint8_t scratchPad[8]; //holding for onewire capture
        readScratchPad(address,scratchPad,channel);
}

void Temperature::readScratchPad(uint8_t rom[8],uint8_t data[8],const     uint8_t &channel)
{
    //read temperature data.
    wireReset(); //reset();
    selectChannel(channel); //necessary on -800
    wireSelect(rom);
    wireWriteByte(0xbe);         // Read Scratchpad command
    //display hex values of scratchpad
    for ( int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {           // we need 9 bytes
        data[i] = wireReadByte();
    }
}
```

The only other thing it could be is that I am passing a pointer to a function incorrectly like this:

```
function getNext()
{
     uint8_t address[8];
     getNextAddress(address);
}

bool Temperature::getNextAddress(uint8_t *vAddress)
{
    if ( !wireSearch(vAddress))
    {
        wireResetSearch();
        wireReset();
        wireSkip();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I was passing the pointer as getNext(&address[8]), but it did not work either.
 Thanks,

Comment: The array passing (which amounts to nothing more than passing an address anyway) appears correct in both code snippets. It is most-certainly *wrong* in the last line of your question, so just don't do that. You need to run your program through a debugger and/or valgrind. We have no way of further helping on this, as we most-certainly cannot reproduce your problem with what we have.

Comment: Ya I am sorry I know you can not duplicate it, but is on a PCB, so I can not attach a debugger, trust me I would if I could. So do not do &array[0] when passing to pointer in function then. Correct?

Comment: The only possible problem I can see is the possibility of `wireSearch` or `wireSelect` writing more than eight `uint8_t`s.

Comment: The comment `// we need 9 bytes` doesn't match the code, though. If something else is depending on your actually reading nine bytes, that could cause problems.

Comment: @DonaldBoissonneault `&address[0]` isn't in your final sentence. `&address[8] ` is what you presented, and it is certainly wrong. And `&address[0] ` is pointless in itself. It is equivalent to `address` in any expression context expecting a pointer-to-base, so unless you're looking to type characters for fun, there's no sense in `&address[0] ` regardless; `address` will suffice.

Comment: I am going to look into this 9 bytes thing.

Comment: You're reading a bunch of things, only to immediately discard them. Is that on purpose?

Comment: Suggestion: If you cannot debug on your target hardware, debug as much as you can on hardware that you can debug. Test the living smurf out of your program on a PC, for example, and when you know the logic is sound, run it on the target to resolve the finicky details. This may require you to write code that abstracts or simulates the hardware, but writing the this "stub" code often takes less time than trying to debug by trial and guesswork.